# Why I have to contain a badge image when update tile in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, tile

I found when I create a update tile app, if set a badge in appxmanifest, the app works, but if I delete the badge image, there will be a exception "Element not found" throws out. My template is TileWideText05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badge images are usually required when you have the app to set to run in lock-screen mode. This means the app will run in the background and use the badge icon to update the lock screen with details. If you are not using this functionality, simply turn off run in lock screen and you will not be required to provide an image.